# Making image clickable without anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make a image in  tag clickable without surrounding it with anchor tag.

Purpose is that I have used cfyon script from yahoo to make a scrolling marquee of images. The marquee is fine but the requirement includes making each picture of the marquee clickable. Onclick, a javascript function will be called. These images are fed to the script using the following code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.now();
    var marqueecontent = '<img src="marequee/DSC_11801.jpg" width="281" height="250" alt="Monique Relander"  class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"/><img src="marequee/DSC_10541.jpg" width="274" height="250" alt="Monique Relander" /><img src="marequee/leather-chairs1.jpg" width="221" height="250" alt="Monique Relander" /><img src="marequee/tassel-lamp.jpg" width="194" height="250" alt="Monique Relander" /><img src="marequee/angellamp.jpg" width="162" height="250" alt="Monique Relander" /><img src="marequee/daybed.jpg" width="384" height="250" alt="Monique Relander" /><img src="marequee/birdcage.jpg" width="208" height="250" alt="Monique Relander" /><img src="marequee/oakchair.jpg" width="161" height="250" alt="Monique Relander" /><img src="marequee/candelabras.jpg" width="188" height="250" alt="Monique Relander" />';
  </script>
```

Surrounding individual  tags with  is not working.

The anchor tag look like

Please help!

Comment: What about the "onclick" event directly on the image ?

Comment: I tried but the image is not clickable.

Comment: Use jQuery.  $('img').on('click', function(){...});

Comment: The anchor that I want to remove looks like this....      <a id="item" href="image_max.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this,{wrapperClassName: 'wide-border', captionOverlay: { position: 'rightpanel'}})">

Comment: @Joe jQuery is a 32kb solution to a 50byte problem. It's never wise to add unnecessary bloat to your projects. Click handlers are a trivial thing and easily accomplished with raw JavaScript.

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle i put together, you can view source to see how it works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say you have an image like so

```
<img id="example" src="blah.jpg" />
```

You can make this clickable by styling it with css:

```
#example
  {
    cursor:pointer;
  }
```

and then using javascript + jquery library

```
$("#example").click(function() {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.co.uk'
});
```

EDIT:
I put together a jsfiddle to show this in action : http://jsfiddle.net/sn6um/1/show/

Comment: I wrote something like this...........................................                  <style type="text/css">
 #example
   {
     cursor:pointer;
   }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="highslide/highslide-with-gallery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.now();
 var marqueecontent = '<img id="test" src="marequee/DSC_11801.jpg" width="281" height="250" alt="Monique Relander" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"/>';
  $("#example").click(function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.co.uk'
});
  </script>I tried this with firebug. No errors but not clickable

Comment: you have to add id='example' in your img tag or change $("#example"). for this $("#test"). and this #example for #test

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="image" src="submit.gif" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_alt

Don't know when the options for "type=" for the input tag expanded but "image", "date", "number" are a wee revelation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please write a comment instead.

Comment: didn't realise the propriety police would be on to me so quickly - I was mid-edit

Comment: No problem. First, make sure you have written everything and then post the answer. Also, there is no propriety police here XD ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the jquery library and do something like that

```
$("img").click(function (){/*Here you put your action*/});
```

Comment: in addition to this answer it is good to style the img to have a cursor pointer so that a user knows that it is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options for solving this. First would be to build the images in JavaScript and add them tot he container. During this process you could attach the click handlers. Secondly you could add the handlers after you set the html content of the marquee. Let's look at both approaches:

#### Building Images With JavaScript

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'foo.png';
myImage.onclick = function(){
  alert( 'You clicked me' );
};
...
marqueeContainer.appendChild( myImage );
```

This would need to be done once for each image you have.

#### Set the HTML Content, then Add Event Handlers

```
var myHTML = '<img src="foo.png" />';
marqueeContainer.innerHTML = myHTML;
marqueeContainer.images[0].onclick = function(){
  alert( 'You clicked me' );
};
```

This method lets you use your current variable which contains all of your images and their attributes.

Comment: I thied this and got a scrolling [object HTMLImageElement]

Comment: @aman.kejriwal Do not set `innerHTML` to be the image object. Make sure you use `appendChild` instead.

Comment: @aman.kejriwal Have you had any luck implementing either of the two solutions above?

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle i put together, you can view source to see how it works

Comment: @Sam Your solution requires jQuery. This is like putting on the Ironman suit to keep from stubbing a toe.

Comment: True, although i didnt have an answer using just javascript. I actually meant to post it on the question. Sorry about that!

Comment: @GregM Touché - if I could wear it to avoid stubbing toes, I definitely would. But hopefully you get my point :)