# "Click to enlarge" a plain <img> tag with pure CSS and no HTML changes

Tags: html, css, image, markdown

I'm working on a website where I only have control over (part of) the CSS code. I can't add JavaScript code, and I also can't change the HTML of webpages (because it comes from a Markdown compiler, and although Markdown supports inserting HTML tags, the content is written without them to keep the HTML abstracted).

Some webpages have images. These appear as plain (generated) `<img>` tags. I want to allow the user to "click to enlarge" these images. This functionality is apparently called a *lightbox*.

So, I want to support this for all these plain `<img>` tags *in pure CSS and without adding extra HTML*. I've found many solutions, but none satisfy this specification:

- A lot of them use jQuery, e.g. all of [these examples](https://v3.osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/). A lot of what I've found is actually meant for *galleries*, like [this one](https://www.codingnepalweb.com/responsive-image-lightbox-javascript/) which uses JavaScript. Same for [this entire library](https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/).
- [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036597/how-to-enlarge-an-image-on-hover-or-click) just enlarges the image on hovering, rather than isolating it. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246671/making-image-clickable-without-anchor-tag) doesn't require any extra HTML, but needs JavaScript. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70081684/image-grow-to-screen-size-on-click-css-html) is the same. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51054042/9352077) has a similar title to mine, but is actually completely different from what I want. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813699/how-to-change-an-image-on-click-using-css-alone) is about swapping images, and the proposed solution is to use an `<input>` tag, which I can't.
- The best one I've found is [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/nebo/pen/ONXejO), but it requires an `<a>` anchor tag around each `<img>` tag and apparently an additional pair of tags for the lightbox itself. The reason is that the `<a>` tag can change the fragment of the URL, and subsequently CSS can detect that change using `:target`. Same for [this website](http://sylviavanos.nl/CSSBox/).

I don't need any gallery functionality with buttons. I literally just need any `<img>` tag to be clickable so it appears (perhaps with a zoom transition) in the center of the screen with a dimmed background, and clicking anywhere restores the page to normal.

---

**Edit:** Although some of the above threads don't provide any code in the question themselves *and* I described the givens on my end (which is just `<img src="..."/>`), here is a minimised version of that last Codepen:

```css
* body {
    background-color: white;
} 

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.trans {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.top {
    display: flex;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10vh;
}

.top ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top ul li::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    content: '';
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.4;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.top ul li:hover::before {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.90);
}

.top ul li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lightbox {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.lightbox img {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
    position: relative;
    top: -100%;
    /* Transition */
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.lightbox:target {
    outline: none;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: all 1.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease;
}
.lightbox:target img {
    top: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#img_1"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/road-curve-landscape_426-19324358.jpg"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#_1" class="lightbox trans" id="img_1"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/road-curve-landscape_426-19324358.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Generally it's because there's nothing to debug, it's considered off topic to ask for ideas rather than try something and ask specific questions

Comment: I didn't vote, but I don't see any code where you tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I provided 10 links, including to threads on the website, as proof of work, and the Codepen at the bottom is the best MWE I can provide. `<img src="..."/>` is all I have myself.

Comment: "the Codepen at the bottom is the best MWE I have" Code must be on *this site* to be considered a [mre]. We have [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), which provide an environment where you can have runnable code. The 10 links provide good evidence that you've *researched* the problem, which is commendable, but not evidence that you've *tried to solve it yourself*.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It is now on the site. My own attempt used `img:active` which is [just not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215528/css-imghover-working-imgactive-is-not) and cannot be improved without starting from scratch.

Comment: @Phix It is difficult to deduce this principle when threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813699/how-to-change-an-image-on-click-using-css-alone), which I linked and is very similar to my own, receive 20 *up*votes.

Comment: @mew That was asked 12 years ago, and for better or worse, things have changed.

Comment: Can I make sure I definitely understand what is required, you want to sense when an image is clicked (not when it is hovered) for it to expand. And then do you want it to shrink back to normal size on the next click? I ask because I currently can see no way of doing this without for example adding say a checkbox or similarly altering the HTML.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, your description is correct. Click to enlarge (bigger image, center it on the screen, make the rest of the page darker). Click again to do the same but in reverse. I do realise that CSS can't do everything, but I would have thought that this is all basically just fancy markup of the `<img>` tag, making it feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And you want the rest of the page not to move when the img is expanded? It would help to have some idea of the surrounding HTML structure and relevant CSS because doing this for an img all by itself is not the same as doing it for absolutely any img that may be within already positioned elements.

Comment: @AHaworth [These examples](https://v3.osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/) are basically the result I want to achieve (especially the second row), except they use jQuery.

Comment: It appears from comments to answers that you are happy to use Javascript, and this would make it possible(jquery is only JS under the skin). Be wary though of using 'fixed' if an img is within positioned ancestors.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to modify the DOM, and want to handle clicks, CSS simply can't do that, it will just be hacks with `:target` or `:active`.

```css
img { width: 5em}
img:active { width: unset}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/road-curve-landscape_426-19324358.jpg">
```

You have to either use JavaScript, or modify the DOM to use the [`details` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details), who has an `open` state.

---

> Click to enlarge (bigger image, center it on the screen, make the rest
> of the page darker). Click again to do the same but in reverse.

As stated in the comment, here is a way to achieve this click/close effect with only HTML/CSS, but for that we have to use the `details` element.

```css
.popup > p {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.popup summary {
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: auto
}
.popup summary > img {
    width:2em
}
.popup[open] summary > img {
    display: none
}
.popup[open] img {
    width: 90vw
}
.popup[open] summary {
    background: black;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
.popup[open] {
    position: fixed;
    outline: 5000px #00000090 solid;
    border: 5px red solid;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 1;
    max-height: 90vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden
}
.popup[open] summary::after {
    content: '❌';
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<details class="popup">
  <summary><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/road-curve-landscape_426-19324358.jpg"></summary>
    <p>
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/road-curve-landscape_426-19324358.jpg">
    </p>
</details>
```

Comment: I didn't know about `details`, interesting. Nevertheless, changing the compiler is the least possible out of everything I could do. Perhaps there's a way of sneaking JavaScript into the head of each generated page, but then that means moving the goalposts of the question to writing a JavaScript snippet that turns <img> tags into <a><img> tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `tabindex="0"` to the `<img>`, you can apply `:focus`:

```css
img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img:focus {
  --offset: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  inset: var(--offset);
  object-fit: cover;
  width: calc(100dvw - 2 * var(--offset));
  height: calc(100dvh - 2 * var(--offset));
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 var(--offset) rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  z-index: 666;
  cursor: unset;
}

div {
  display: inline-flex;
}

div:has(img:focus) {
  height: 100px; /* same height of image - just jump content prevent */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/road-curve-landscape_426-19324358.jpg" height="100" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

Comment: I like this a lot. Does it work to have `tabindex="0"` for all images on the same page, or do they need to be unique and/or increasing? Either way, I think injecting a tiny piece of JavaScript to add a `tabindex` to all `img` tags on the page should be very doable.

Comment: This is not answering the original question which specified CSS only and no HTML changes. Has the requirement changed and JS is now allowed? If so, please amend the title and description.

Comment: @AHaworth As specified in the question, I wanted pure CSS with no HTML changes. However, as it appears from the two answers, the actual answer to my question is "it cannot be done". This is valuable information to exist on the internet, hence changing the title is not a good idea (I wasted a lot of time on Google not finding a relevant thread). I will likely end up accepting an answer that says *no, it is not possible, but if you grant a negligible amount of JS, here is a solution that does work*.